# Is websocket fallback still necessary nowadays?

Tags: websocket

In the past, websockets were not supported by all browsers and networks.
We were required to provide fallback solutions like HTTP Long Polling.

This situation appeared to change. 
At least the browsers support looks great now: https://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

I could not find any statistics about networks blocking websockets.

Do we have any data proving that there is still a justification for websocket fallback solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Last year, I had an issue using Trello at work. While the page was initially shown, some changes were not reflecting on the page. I investigated using the Chrome debugger and found out that WebSockets connection was blocked (at least for that website).

After a few exchanges with IT, and some firewall black magic on their side, the issue was resolved and now Trello works fine.

So, in a few corporate environments, some WebSockets scenarios still need a fallback IMHO.